# Splitting on group of capital letters in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to tokenize a number of strings using a capital letter as a delimited. I have landed on the following code:

```
token = ([a for a in re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]*)', "ABCowDog") if a])

print token
```

And I get this, as expected, in return:

> ['A', 'B', 'Cow', 'Dog']

Now, this is just an example string to make life easier, but in my case I want to go through this list and find individual characters (easy enough with checking len()) and putting the individual letters together, provided they meet a prior definition. In the example above the strings 'AB', 'Cow', and 'Dog' are the strings I actually want to form (consecutive capitals are part of an acronym). For whatever reason, once I have my token, I am unable to figure out how to walk the list. Sorry if this is a simple answer, but I'm fairly new to python and am sick of banging my head against the wall.

Answer (score 3):

`re.split` isn't always easy to use and seems sometimes limited in many situations. You can try a different approach with `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = 'ABCowDog'
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Z](?:[A-Z]*(?![a-z])|[a-z]*)', s)
['AB', 'Cow', 'Dog']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to split with [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex):

```
(?=[A-Z][a-z])
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fS3fE1/4)

Code:

```
regex.split(r'(?=[A-Z][a-z])', "ABCowDog",flags=regex.VERSION1)
```

Comment: `re.split` does not split on `0 width assertions`.Use `regex` module instead

Answer (score 0):

```
([A-Z][a-z]+)
```

You should split by this.